# filtering to have unique date and time to the hour

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I have a large data set with data points collected sporadically through time. Basically it is GPS tracking data, which is collected when in reach of receiver antennae - however, the resolution can be, at times, too high e.g. every minute or so - which is unnecessary and makes mapping it a processing challenge, so I would like to reduce it.

The best way I can thing of is too somehow filter the data so that the date and time to the hour is unique - this would reduce the number of minute data points. However, it has to be done by an individual identifier too - in this case the "Name". Because some dates/times might cross over with the objects with different names.

I am not particularly bothered which row is selected based on the individual hour and it doesn't need to be averaged etc. Any thoughts on the best approach to this?

Here is some dummy data:

```
df <- structure(list(`Local Time` = structure(c(1559388960, 1559389200, 
1559394840, 1559397180, 1559397900, 1559398380, 1559398560, 1559398680, 
1559398740, 1559398800, 1559399160, 1559399280, 1559399400, 1559399580, 
1559399640, 1559399820, 1559399940, 1559400120, 1559400240, 1559400780, 
1559400840, 1559400960, 1559401080, 1559401260, 1559401380, 1559383560, 
1559389200, 1559389440, 1559395080, 1559395320, 1559397180, 1559397900, 
1559398200, 1559398440, 1559398680, 1559398920, 1559399220, 1559399520, 
1559399820, 1559400120, 1559400360, 1559400660, 1559400960, 1559401200, 
1559401500, 1559401740, 1559402040, 1559402280, 1559402580, 1559402880
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), COG = c(315, 
352.6, 265.6, 214.9, 240.8, 245.5, 240.3, 250.5, 262.4, 269.8, 
281.1, 262.9, 253.1, 247.7, 255.5, 249.4, 263.2, 268.6, 279.6, 
274.3, 254.6, 246.6, 253.7, 242.3, 163.5, 90, 88, 89, 93, 96, 
95, 97, 97, 98, 98, 95, 93, 94, 92, 91, 91, 91, 91, 90, 90, 92, 
89, 89, 89, 88), NAME = c("Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", 
"Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", 
"Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", "Aur", 
"Aur", "Aur", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", 
"Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", 
"Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos", "Cos"
 )), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: [`round.POSIXt`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/round.POSIXt) your timestamps, then using `by` or `dplyr::group_by(x, name, roundedtime)` or `data.table`'s `x[,,by=c("name","roundedtime")]` method, take the first, last, or random row from each rounded timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `round.POSIXt` (and `as.POSIXct`, since the former returns `POSIXlt`, and `dplyr` doesn't like those):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(NAME, rtime = as.POSIXct(round.POSIXt(`Local Time`, units = "hours"))) %>%
  slice(1)
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
# # Groups:   NAME, rtime [9]
#   `Local Time`          COG NAME  rtime              
#   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr> <dttm>             
# 1 2019-06-01 04:36:00  315  Aur   2019-06-01 05:00:00
# 2 2019-06-01 06:14:00  266. Aur   2019-06-01 06:00:00
# 3 2019-06-01 06:53:00  215. Aur   2019-06-01 07:00:00
# 4 2019-06-01 07:30:00  253. Aur   2019-06-01 08:00:00
# 5 2019-06-01 03:06:00   90  Cos   2019-06-01 03:00:00
# 6 2019-06-01 04:40:00   88  Cos   2019-06-01 05:00:00
# 7 2019-06-01 06:18:00   93  Cos   2019-06-01 06:00:00
# 8 2019-06-01 06:53:00   95  Cos   2019-06-01 07:00:00
# 9 2019-06-01 07:32:00   94  Cos   2019-06-01 08:00:00
```

If you prefer, you can instead return the *last* with `slice(n())` or a random row with `sample_n(1)`.

Comment: Just to confirm slice(1) just takes the first row of that individual identifier?

Comment: Yes. `x %>% slice(1)` is analogous to `x[1,]`, and `x %>% slice(n())` is `x[nrow(x),]` (assuming `x` is the portion of the frame specific to that identifier/group).

Answer (score 1):

It can be also done in `data.table`; given your dataset size, I think this would save you some computational resources:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[1], by=list(NAME, DateTime = substr(`Local Time`,1, 13))]

#    NAME      DateTime   COG
# 1:  Aur 2019-06-01 07 315.0
# 2:  Aur 2019-06-01 09 265.6
# 3:  Aur 2019-06-01 10 240.8
# 4:  Aur 2019-06-01 11 242.3
# 5:  Cos 2019-06-01 06  90.0
# 6:  Cos 2019-06-01 07  88.0
# 7:  Cos 2019-06-01 09  93.0
# 8:  Cos 2019-06-01 10  97.0
# 9:  Cos 2019-06-01 11  90.0
```

You can also use `.SD[.N]` to get the last row.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - just for my understanding here can you explain the substr function and the 1,13?

Comment: Lmm, try `substr("hello world", 2, 5)` to see what that function does. There are more examples in [`?substr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/substr).